# Organizing multiple onChange events

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events

I have 8 forms on the page. Each form changes the values of its corresponding graph without refreshing the page. However, I'd like to make it so that I don't have to hit the submit button in order to change the graphs. I have 3 form elements for each form. This means that I need 3 `onChange` events for every form. I would need 24 `onChange` events for the whole page. Each `onChange` event calls a unique function only to that graph. So inside each `onChange` event is a unique function with the parameters supplied by the `onChange` event.

What i'd like to know is that is there a way to reduce the number of `onChange` events? Writing out 24 events makes me wonder if there is a simpler way of doing it. Is there?

Comment: You would need those 24 unique functions in any case? Or are they differing by the parameters only?

Comment: Not sure if you just want to simplify firing logic or the entire process. You can simplify firing logic by adding on change to groups with jQuery selector -- i.e `$(".in").change()` for all of a certain class.

Comment: `$(document).on('change', 'form :input', function(){ console.log(this) })`

Comment: @Teemu They are differing by only parameter. So in general, there will be 8 unique functions

Comment: Please check [this improved fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zgc90v7/1/). jQuery has methods to `data-*` exctracting, you can use those instead of native attribute getters, ofcourse. If you need the value of an input to be passed as a parameter too, you can push it to `params` array before calling the final handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need 1 eventHandler, and you can send in different ids that you check for. Something like this.

```js
function onChangeInput(id) {
  switch (id) {
    case 1:
      console.log('Update form 1');
      break;

    case 2:
      console.log('Update form 2');
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Form 1</label><br>
  <input type="text" onchange="onChangeInput(1)">
  <input type="text" onchange="onChangeInput(1)">
</form>

<form>
  <label>Form 2</label><br>
  <input type="text" onchange="onChangeInput(2)">
  <input type="text" onchange="onChangeInput(2)">
</form>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thank you!

Comment: @user2896120 I bet this is not what you really want.

Comment: You could add the onChange handler by code. But I think this is more understandable.

Comment: @Teemu Hmm how so?

Comment: @user2896120 Using inline listeners is not generally preferred, and you'd get a huge `switch` statement. You could delegate the event on the closest ancestor of all the forms, and store the unique function name and parameters to `data-*` attributes in the elements instead.

Comment: @Teemu How would that be achieved?

Comment: You could add an Id to the form, and get it from the input event inside the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun here is another way to improve the solution.

First every form gets an Id. Then inside the event handler you could get that id by doing `this.parentNode.id`. Now the input element do not need to know what form it should update.

And at last you could add the event handler to the input elements by query them and use `addEventListener`

```js
var q = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

function updateForm(id) {
  console.log(id);
  document.getElementById('output').textContent = "Change detected in Form: " + id;
}

function onChangeEvent(event) {
  updateForm(this.parentNode.id);
}

var allInputs = q('form input');
allInputs.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('change', onChangeEvent);
});
```

```html
<form id="1">
  <label>Form 1</label><br>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</form>
<br>
<form id="2">
  <label>Form 2</label><br>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</form>
<br>
<form id="3">
  <label>Form 3</label><br>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</form>
<br>
<div id="output"></div>
```