# jQuery onChange Event multiple inputs

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="text" id="Count1"  value="20">
<input type="text" id="Count2"  value="30"> 
<input type="text" id="Count3"  value="40"> 
<input type="text" id="Count4"  value="50"> 
<input type="text" id="Count5"  value="60"> 
<div class="inputbox" id="Sum"> ConunSUM </div>
```

I have multiple inputs,May be up to 50,How should i use onchange,
Do automatic totalization Bring to Sum.

Comment: What have you tried?  The jQuery `change` handler is well documented with a variety of examples: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: this is a similar question I wish it help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45443534/organizing-multiple-onchange-events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```js
$(".value").on("input", function() 
{
  var sum = 0;
  $('.value').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
  });
  $("#sum").html(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="value" value="20">
<input type="text" class="value" value="15">
<div class="inputbox" id="sum"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `input` event and then sum up all the values.

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  $('#Sum').text(sum());
});

$('#Sum').text(sum());

function sum() {
  let sum = 0;
  
  $('input').each(function() {
    let value = Number(this.value);

    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      sum += value;
    }
  });
  
  return sum;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Count1" value="20">
<input type="text" id="Count2" value="30">
<input type="text" id="Count3" value="40">
<input type="text" id="Count4" value="50">
<input type="text" id="Count5" value="60">
<div class="inputbox" id="Sum"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to use id here? Because I still have some hidden input.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether your input fields are hidden or not. This solution should work given you have a collection of input text fields.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow,
You can make all inputs as Number like
`<input type="number" id="Count1"  value="20">`
and then using

```
$('body').on('change','input[type="number"]',function () {

var sum = 0;    
$.each($('input'), function (index,element) {
sum += Number($(element).val());    
});

$('#Sum').text(sum);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For each used got it sum calculation. Hope this helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    get_sum();
  });
});
get_sum();

function get_sum() {
  var sum = 0;
  $("input[type='text']").each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $('.inputbox').html(sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Count1" value="20">
<input type="text" id="Count2" value="30">
<input type="text" id="Count3" value="40">
<input type="text" id="Count4" value="50">
<input type="text" id="Count5" value="60">
<div class="inputbox" id="Sum"> ConunSUM </div>
```